# changing spacing of caption

Tags: spacing, captions, lyx

I'm creating a figure using LyX. I would like the spacing of the caption below the figure to be 1.3. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Setting the spacing to 1.3 for the entire document using the setspace command doesn't seem to work.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{...}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{...}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: Adding `\linespread{1.3}\selectfont{}` in an ERT within the caption, is that what you mean?

Comment: That's perfect. One other question: Is there any way to change the font size to 11.5?

Comment: `\fontsize{11.5}\selecfont{}`

Comment: By the way, `\begin{centering}` is wrong: just use `\centering` and remove `\par\end{centering}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can we add `\linespread{1.3}` default for all figures?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless the exact value of font size is very important, you can use the features of the `caption` package. (If it is, see *Old answer* below.)

Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

If you want to change *all* the captions in your document to a larger font with added linespacing, add the following line to the preamble as well:

```
\captionsetup{font={large,stretch=1.3}}
```

or if you want it to apply to tables only,

```
\captionsetup[table]{font={large,stretch=1.3}}
```

`caption` allows you to customize your captions a lot, see [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) for details.

If you want to apply this to just a single caption, add an ERT within the table/figure float, before the caption, and write the `\captionsetup` there.

### Old answer

I'm not sure why you want this, and I wouldn't do myself, but if you're doing this for a single caption, you can add an ERT at the beginning of the caption containing

```
\linespread{1.3}\selectfont{}
```

To change the font size as well, use

```
\fontsize{11.5}{13.8}\linespread{1.3}\selectfont{}
```

The second argument to `\fontsize` is the baselineskip, set to 1.2 times the font size.

This does not, however, change the size of *Table 1*. To change that you can use the `caption` package, as explained above, and use `labelfont={large}`.

Comment: I'm using the article class

Comment: @user30501 See my edited answer. Feel free to upvote and/or accept it if you found it helpful.

Comment: @user30501 Instead of snippets of tex code, Please include [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` in this way we know the full information including class.

Comment: When using the `caption` package anyway one could use that package to setup the line spacing inside captions (globally), too, so there is no need anymore to change every single caption.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Excellent point, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 13):

In order to make @Torbjørn T. code function correctly, it is *extremely* necessary to load the `setspace` package in your preamble (and of course, copy the `setspace.sty` into the `/texmf` folder). This is due to we are using the `stretch` option in the `\captionsetup` declaration.

Of course Caption Package can change caption's line space, with the `stretch` option, *but* it is necessary to load *both* `caption` and `setspace` packages. (Page 38 from: http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf )

So, the code would be:

```
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\captionsetup{font={large,stretch=1.3}}
```

Otherwise, only making:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={large,stretch=1.3}}
```

would not function.

Comment: setspace inclusion made the difference.  Thanks.